# Writing to ssh.Session.StdinPipe() is hanging

Tags: go, pipe

I'm using go's ssh module, and I'm trying to pipe input from my program to the remote shell over stdin. This works as expected, printing `Hello World`:

```
mySession := PrepareSession()  // helper method to prepare a Connection and Session object
output, _ := mySession.Output("echo Hello World")
fmt.Println(output)
```

When I try to provide stdin input, however, it hangs on the line `myStdin.Write("Hello World")` (I've confirmed this with a debugger):

```
mySession := PrepareSession()
myStdin, _ := mySession.StdinPipe()
myStdin.Write("Hello World")
output, _ := mySession.Output("cat /dev/stdin | echo")
fmt.Println(output)
```

Replacing `myStdin.Write("Hello World")` with `fmt.Fprint(myStdin, "Hello World")` yields the same problem.

Overall I just don't understand how pipes work in Go - how do I get the pipe to stop hanging when I feed input to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StdinPipe` is the standard input for the **remote command**, as mentioned in [the docs](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.StdinPipe).

Your second example attempts to write to stdin on the remote host without running a command. Since there is no remote command, there is no consumer for stdin, hanging forever.

Instead, you should do something similar to the [Output](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.Output) method:

```
func (s *Session) Output(cmd string) ([]byte, error) {
    if s.Stdout != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("ssh: Stdout already set")
    }
    var b bytes.Buffer
    s.Stdout = &b
    err := s.Run(cmd)  <---- you need to run a command on the remote host.
    return b.Bytes(), err
}
```

Comment: This worked - loading my file into a `var myBytes []byte` and then assigning `mySession.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(myBytes)` made it so that the input was finally accepted (at least when I send the command `echo $(cat /dev/stdin)`. Piping `cat /dev/stdin | echo` didn't work, for whatever reason, but that's a separate issue)